# TS compiler API: prevent Export. to appear on nodes where there is not a export modifier

Tags: typescript, export, typescript-compiler-api

in js an exported variable is declared like: 
`"Exports.my_var = cool_value "`,

when using the Typyscript compiler api i have some varibales that originally have the export modifier like:

```
export let a = 1;
a = a + 1;
```

that resolves in

```
Exports.a = 1;
Exports.a = Exports.a + 1;
```

but i don't want them to be exported in the js file, i tried removing the export modifiers on the nodes, but they are still compiled with the Exports.

**[UPDATE]**

some example code

**Transformer:**

```
 ast = VisitNode(ast,function() {
                let visitor = (n) => {
                    console.log('VISITING',n.kind);
                    if(n.modifiers) {
                        n.modifiers = undefined;
                        console.log(n.modifiers);
                    }

                    return visitEachChild(n,visitor,ctx);
                }

                return visitor;
            }());

 return ast;
```

**VisitNode** and **visitEachChild** are custom function, but work as the ts. ones.

**test.ts:**

```
export let a = 30;
export let z = 10;

z = z + a;
a = a + z;
export let c = 'hello';
c = 'hey there';
```

**output:**

```
exports.a = 30;
exports.z = 10;
exports.z = exports.z + exports.a;
exports.a = exports.a + exports.z;
exports.c = 'hello';
exports.c = 'hey there';
```

Comment: Could you post your code to show how the transform is being done and how that ties into the whole process of ending up with a js file?

Comment: updated question with some code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems one way to do it is to set all the identifiers to have a `LocalName` emit flag and remove the internal `externalModuleIndicator` property on the source file.

```
const transformer = <T extends ts.Node>(context: ts.TransformationContext) =>
    (rootNode: T) => {
        function visit(sourceFile: ts.Node): ts.Node {
            if (!ts.isSourceFile(sourceFile))
                throw new Error("This code only works with a source file.");

            // strip this internal property to get rid of `exports.__esModule = true;`
            delete (sourceFile as any).externalModuleIndicator;

            return ts.visitEachChild(sourceFile, statement => {
                // remove the export modifiers
                if (statement.modifiers) {
                    const newModifiers = statement.modifiers
                        .filter(m => m.kind !== ts.SyntaxKind.ExportKeyword);
                    statement.modifiers = ts.createNodeArray(newModifiers);
                }

                return ts.visitEachChild(statement, visitIdentifiers, context);

                function visitIdentifiers(descendant: ts.Node) {
                    if (ts.isIdentifier(descendant))
                        return ts.setEmitFlags(descendant, ts.EmitFlags.LocalName);
                    return ts.visitEachChild(descendant, visitIdentifiers, context);
                }
            }, context);
        }
        return ts.visitNode(rootNode, visit);
    };
```

Basically, the compiler collects all the names to export before the transformation phase, then it substitutes all the identifiers that match an exported name to have an `exports.` prefix. So stripping the `export` modifier has no effect because the compiler has already decided what names to export.

Comment: Seems kind of sketch. Are you sure you want to be doing this when compiling? What about just using `ts.transform` and then printing the result?