# Compile typescript module to plain web javascript via compiler api

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

I have a node script where I want to compile a ts file with a exported function to javascript that can be used on the web / embedded into a script tag.

```js
const ts = require("typescript");

// hard coded for demonstration
const typescriptCode = `
export function add(a: number, b: number): number {
    return a + b;
}`;

let result = ts.transpile(typescriptCode, { 
    compilerOptions: { 
        module: ts.ModuleKind.None,
        target: ts.ScriptTarget.ES5
    }
});
```

However even with `ts.ModuleKind.None` used in the compile options the program still outputs a script that attempts to bind the function to exports. Exports is not valid on the web. Value of `result`:

```js
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
function add(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}
exports.add = add;
```

How can I only transpile to this / make `result` be:

```js
function add(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

Comment: What if you remove the `export` from the function ? Since you don't want modules you should not use module features such as imports and exports

Comment: I think you might be looking for something like the answer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58793176/188246 (there is a `transformers` property on `TranspileOptions`).

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Unfortunately that export is required by a separate process. I think my best bet is to remove export keywords from `typescriptCode` via regex replace before transpile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a different value for [`module`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#module):

```js
const source = `export function add(a: number, b: number): number {
  return a + b;
}`;

transpile(source, { module: 'ESNext', target: 'ESNext' });
```

Will yield:

```js
export function add(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}
```